# How to back track my index to have my data in the right place

Tags: python, indexing, filter, find

Currently I'm trying to find the word "stolen base" in my list. I did find the word "stolen base". In my dataframe these are my results.

```
Hitters     Play by Play                                                                                                                                 Stolen Base
Player A    'Swinging Strike, Ball, Player A advances to 1st (hit by pitch),'                                                                                0
Player B    'Swinging Strike, Swinging Strike, Ball, Player A advances to 2nd (stolen base), Player B putout (strike out swinging) for out number 2,'        1
Player C    'Swinging Strike, Swinging Strike, Ball, Player C advances to 1st (single), Player A advances to 3rd ( 2), Player A Scores Earned ( 22),'        0
Player D    'Ball, Ball, Player D advances to 1st (single), Player C advances to 2nd (27),'                                                                  0
Player E    'Ball, Swinging Strike, Swinging Strike, Ball, Player E putout (strike out swinging) for out number 3,'                                          0
```

However I need my dataframe to end like this

```
Hitters     Play by Play                                                                                                                                 Stolen Base
Player A    'Swinging Strike, Ball, Player A advances to 1st (hit by pitch),'                                                                                1
Player B    'Swinging Strike, Swinging Strike, Ball, Player A advances to 2nd (stolen base), Player B putout (strike out swinging) for out number 2,'        0
Player C    'Swinging Strike, Swinging Strike, Ball, Player C advances to 1st (single), Player A advances to 3rd ( 2), Player A Scores Earned ( 22),'        0
Player D    'Ball, Ball, Player D advances to 1st (single), Player C advances to 2nd (27),'                                                                  0
Player E    'Ball, Swinging Strike, Swinging Strike, Ball, Player E putout (strike out swinging) for out number 3,'                                          0
```

Since I'm new to python, I can't think of a way to have my code back track and put it in the right place. This is just a sample of an inning and each inning can vary wildly so indexing [1:5] won't work because the stolen base could occur in the second play by play or 5 play by play

The current code that I'm using is to find "stolen base" in the play by play is this

```
hitters = ['Player A', 'Player B', 'Player C', 'Player D', 'Player E']

play_by_play = ['Swinging Strike, Ball, Player A advances to 1st (hit by pitch),',
                'Swinging Strike, Swinging Strike, Ball, Player A advances to 2nd (stolen base), 
                 Player B putout (strike out swinging) for out number 2,',' Swinging Strike, 
                 Swinging Strike, Ball, Player C advances to 1st (single), Player A advances 
                 to 3rd ( 2), Player A Scores Earned ( 22),','Ball, Ball, Player D advances to 1st
                 (single), Player C advances to 2nd (27),','Ball, Swinging Strike, Swinging Strike,
                 Ball, Player E putout (strike out swinging) for out number 3,']


stolen_base = "stolen base"

stolen_bases = []
for i in range(0,len(game)):
    if stole in game[i]:
        stolen = 1
        stolen_bases.append(stolen)
    else:
        not_stolen = 0
        stolen_bases.append(not_stolen)
```

Comment: what is the return value you need at the end? is it a list? or just True False

Comment: a list so I can put it into my dataframe

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have the text as a list of strings.
you can go through them like this:

```
list_of_strings = ['String1', 'string 2', 'String @@', 'string 65']

has_key = []
key_word = "S"
for s in list_of_strings:
    has_key.append(1 if key_word in s else 0)

complete_list = list(zip(list_of_strings, has_key))
```

just use your lists and zip all of them together

Comment: While this will get me a list of [0,1,0,0,0] when I plug in my variable into your formula, my formula of my current code get me the same result. 

I need a code that will find "stolen base" which you have provided but then I need to some how find the name it goes to so the list is in the right order. 

Currently the list is [0,1,0,0,0] but I need the list to be [1,0,0,0,0]

Comment: I looked at your data again, there is no "stolen base" at the first string....

Comment: Player B    'Swinging Strike, Swinging Strike, Ball, Player A advances to 2nd (stolen base), Player B putout (strike out swinging) for out number 2,'. 

This happens in Player B at bat. So in code and mine, it will return a 1 for Player B but in reality it should go to Player A because he's the one that actually stole the base

Comment: You are looking at it as a one long string? And you want to find the last player before "stolen base"?

Comment: I am looking for the last player before "stolen base". However, Players A- E are there own list, the play by play is its own list, and i want to make a list for the people that stole a base. Does that help?

Comment: You want a list of the first people name that came before an appearance of a "stolen base" in the string?

Comment: I would like a list of people name who name appears with stolen base in the string. Which then can change the name to the number of times they stole during that inning